# Is the "read contacts" permission per account or per device?

Tags: contacts, whatsapp-messenger, permissions

I have two accounts on my phone (Android 7.1.2)

If one app has "read contacts" permission can it read the contacts for all my accounts or only the account I install it or use it as?

Does it change the answer if the app *also* has "find accounts" or any other permission?

This question is motivated by the WhatsApp app, but it would apply to many others.

Comment: Thanks @iBug  It certainly looks useful.

I'll probably close this as duplicate soon.